# Weblogic server won’t start, because a bad.jar was deployed in it. But I can’t start the admin console, in order to remove the .jar

Tags: weblogic, undeploy

My Weblogic server was running fine inside my Eclipse.  But then I accidentally deployed an .ear into my Weblogic server (using the server's Admin Console) which conflicts with another .ear, and now my Weblogic server won't start up.  I know how to remove the .ear.  The way to remove it is to go to the Admin Console, choose Deployments, checkmark the offending .ear and then choose stop and delete.  But I can't get to the Admin Console because the Weblogic server won't start up.

I want to undeploy it, but I can't, because I can't start up the Admin Console.  I also tried undeploying it with the command line, but the command requires communicating with a running server.

The error message in the Eclipse console says:   "Failed to initialize the application 'EILoggingSharedLib [LibSpecVersion=2.22,LibImplVersion=2.22]" due to error weblogic.application.library.LibraryDeploymentException: [J2EE:160145]Failed to deploy library Extension-Name: EILoggingSharedLib, Specification-Version: 2.9, Implementation-Version: 2.9, because of conflicting library Manifest values, and library information registered with the server: [Specification-Version: 2.9 vs. 2.22, Implementation-Version: 2.9 vs. 2.22]. Check the library MANIFEST.MF file and correct version information there to match server settings, or undeploy the misconfigured library."

This is the command line command I used:

C:\bea12c\wlserver\server\lib>java -cp weblogic.jar weblogic.Deployer -verbose -noexit -adminurl http://localhost:7016 -username (myusername) -password (mypassword) -name Dev12c -undeploy EILoggingSharedLib -timeout 300

weblogic.Deployer invoked with options:  -verbose -noexit -adminurl http://localhost:7016 -username weblogic -name Dev12c -undeploy EILoggingSharedLib -timeout 300
Unexpected Error Initializing Deployer: weblogic.Deployer$DeployerException: weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.DeployerException: Unable to connect to 'http://localhost:7016': Destination 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 7016 unreachable; nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Could not connect to /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; No available router to destination. Ensure the url represents a running admin server and that the credentials are correct.  If using http protocol, tunneling must be enabled on the admin server.

I also tried starting the server with startweblogic.sh with the following command, using the same ID and password that I use to log into the admin console (when it was running).  But it didn't help:

startweblogic.sh username=(myusername) password=(mypassword)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First, try to remove your application from deployed applications with Eclipse. If it does not work, edit the ${DOMAIN_HOME}/config/config.xml file and remove the declaration of your application. Then start your server.

Comment: Backup your config first

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.  My Weblogic server that had the problem was at http://localhost:7016.  Since it's a localhost server, all the libraries and apps deployed to that localhost are in a directory in my C: drive where my Weblogic server installation is.  I deleted the offending .ear using File Explorer, then the Weblogic server started up fine.  I was able to go into the Admin Console and delete them again from there.  After that, all was good.  Thank you, Emmanuel and Wesley.